# Google App Script Conditional Formatting Problem

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been using below code and trying to change its color to this code that is **#1b2020** and wants to highlight the complete row where it founds the  word **"Trauma"** in Col"F".

But it just highlight the Cell from Col"A" instead of highlighting the complete row till **"A1:L"**.

And please also share that how to change fonts color when conditional formatting applies.

Your help will be highlight appreciated.

```
   function Formatting() {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var LRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rangeToHighlight = sheet.getRange("A1:L" + LRows);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenFormulaSatisfied('=INDIRECT("R[0]C[5]", FALSE)="Trauma"')
      .setBackground("#1b1919")
      .setFontColor("white") // or use hex equivalent #ffffff
      .setRanges([rangeToHighlight])
      .build();

  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Formatting() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg=sh.getRange(1,6,sh.getLastRow());//getting columnF only
  const vA=rg.getValues();
  const lc=sh.getLastColumn();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[0]=='Trauma') {
      sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,lc).setBackground('#1b2020').setFontColor('#ffffff');//they both return a range so chaining is available
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that chaining is possible. +1 for this new information

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setBackground` and `setFontColor` instead of using conditional formatting.

```
function Formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  data.forEach(function (row, i){
    if(row[5] == "Trauma") {
      // L = 12th column
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 12).setBackground("#1b1919");
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 12).setFontColor("#ffffff");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize that the font color was supposed to be set to white until I read your answer. +1 for that